# Showing videos instead of images in simple jQuery gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, media-player

so I'd like to do something like this, but with videos instead.

http://workshop.rs/2010/07/create-image-gallery-in-4-lines-of-jquery/

I realize it might not be possible using only four lines of code, but the point of just pressing a thumbnail (img) and then show an embedded video instead of the image... can someone help me with that or point me in the right direction? I do NOT want a slider or use lightbox.